# Why minute is not considering when comparing two times in android?

Tags: android, date-format

I just want to compare a time with a current time.which should not be less than the current time.
here is my code:

```
try {
                    Date p_from=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM").parse(from_time);
                    Date p_to=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM").parse(to_time);
                    Date p_selected=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM").parse(String.valueOf(p_hour[0])+":"+String.valueOf(p_min[0]));


                    if (p_selected.before(p_to)&&p_selected.after(p_from)) {
                        String min_str="";
                        if (p_min[0]<10) {
                            min_str=String.valueOf("0"+p_min[0]);
                        } else {
                            min_str=String.valueOf(p_min[0]);
                        }
                        tv_estimate_time.setText("Pickup On "+String.valueOf(p_hour[0])+":"+min_str);
                        popUpWindow.dismiss();
                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error in time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } catch (ParseException e) {

                Log.d("tttt", "c="+Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                }
```

Here **p_from**- is my start time(say 10:00) and **p_to**-is my end time(17.15),**p_selected**- is my selected time(say 16:55). in p_selected p_hour[0]=16 and p_min[0]=55.

In the if part I am checking whether my time is before the end time and after the start time. In some cases date.before(ddate) and date.after(ddate) is not comparing properly Like it is not considering the minutes it is only considering the hours.

Say if the user had selected 16:55 which is before and after the respective time and in the if part it is returning false and goes to the else part.

Comment: can you try using `mm` for minutes instead of `MM`

Comment: man it is working!!!!!

Comment: great, actually the `MM` 's are for month and not minutes , glad it worked :)

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=java+date+format+mm

Comment: Oh yes....Thanks a lot.@alexei..thanks for marking my ques negative.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Time checker
    private boolean timeCheck(long timeInput){

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long difference = currentTime- timeInput;
        int seconds = (int) (difference / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;

        if( timeInput >= currentTime ){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And then, in your main program call the procedure like this:

```
    //if you kept your time as String
    if(timecheck(Long.valueOf(myTime)))
    {
    //not less than current time
    }else{
    //less than current time
    }
```

I suppose that you kept your time as String. For changing time from Long to String you can use:

```
    String.valueOf(myLongTime);
```

I hope it helps.